# Return objects containing all values if 1 value matches a string

Tags: business-objects

The example below will be nonsensical due to the data I'm actually working with being sensitive, but i've simply just swapped the object names.

Lets say I have a set of businesses, and each business contains a set of store locations where they have stores.
I want to return a list of all businesses that have at least 1 store location in "london", and then count the number of stores those businesses have in all locations.

Attempting to use  `=If([Store location] = "london") Then [Business]` gives me the correct list of businesses, but putting this into a cross table with store locations will only count their london stores, and ignore the others.

I've attempted a few little workarounds such as putting this into it's own variable, and then doing `If([VariableBusiness] = [Business]) Then [Business]` and `If(Count([Store Location = "london") >0) Then [Business]`. But I seem to be going around in circles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing a subquery.

In my example here I am only returning **Account Numbers** and all **Financial Trans Codes** that have their **Financial Trans Date** equal to **Most Recent Full Date** and by virtue of the subquery have at least one transaction where the **Financial Trans Date** equals **Most Recent Full Date** and **Financial Trans Code = 790** (equivalent to **Store Location = "London"** for you).

[image]

You can then create a variable to count the store without having any sort of If statement.

[image]

Alternatvely, if you had a measure in your universe to count the number of locations you could just return that rather than creating a variable like I just did.

Noel